# JPA - Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here is my entity class :

```
@Entity
public class MyData {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Integer id;

   public MyData() {
      // ...
   }

   public MyData(String fieldList, Object ... values) {
       // ...
   }

   // Getters and setters here...
}
```

Later , I want to execute this query :

```
SELECT NEW com.company.MyData('f1,f2,f3',t.f1,t.f2,t.f3) FROM my_data_table t WHERE 1=1
```

And this exception is raised:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [package.MyData]
```

My query can contain 1,2 ,3 ... or more fields.

How can I help my JPA provider (hibernate) finding the constructor ?

**Hibernate 3.6.8**
**JPA 2**
**Java 6**

Comment: What exactly do you want that query to do?  Because afaik what you write is syntactically wrong, but I have no idea of what you want to achieve...

Comment: @fvu I want my query fetch some data from my table and stores this data into my object MyData. The list of fields is generated on the fly

Comment: Instead of use dot notation (...) to pass multiple arguments, try change it to receive/pass an array (in the form Object[] values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem:

```
SELECT NEW com.company.MyData('f1,f2,f3',t) FROM my_data_table t WHERE 1=1
```

And my class looks like this now:

```
@Entity
public class MyData {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Integer id;

   public MyData() {
      // ...
   }

   public MyData(String fieldList, MyData md) {
      // ...
   }

   // Getters and setters here...
}
```